# Susy gallery with AngularJS (ng-repeat) - not filling gaps from ng-hide

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, susy

I'm using Susy's gallery tool to display elements in a grid format. Angular is hiding or showing those grid elements on the fly, depending on user selections. When Angular hides an element in the grid, it attaches a class of `ng-hide` to it. This in turn sets its CSS to `display:none !important`.

The issue is that Susy is calculating the position of each element and not taking into account the items set to `display:none` - it is leaving gaps in the grid when those elements are hidden.

Is it possible to get Susy to *ignore* the hidden elements when laying them out?

I've tried using `:not()` CSS selector, without success - there's still gaps in the layout:

```
.results__result:not(.ng-hide) {
    @include gallery(3 of 12);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass doesn't know anything about the DOM, so Susy doesn't either. To create the gallery layout, susy has to rely on `nth-child` selectors — which don't work well for the use-case you are talking about. Start simple:

```
.results__result {
  @include span(3 of 12);
}
```

If you are using `split`, `inside`, or `inside-static` gutters — that should just work. Otherwise you need some way to target the `last` element in each row of the grid. CSS doesn't have a way to target nth-visible, so this would require added logic in your markup/js. Given a `last` class every 4th visible result, you can add:

```
.last {
  @include last;
}
```